# Adding extension to Tcl/Tk macOS Frameworks

Tags: macos, frameworks, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have been able to successfully compile Tcl/Tk Frameworks on macOS (following instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53777217/find-precompiled-or-compile-tcl-tk-frameworks-for-macos)). I use these Frameworks inside an .app for distributions. I would like to customize my Frameworks adding extra extensions, for example Drag&Drop TkDND (by the way, I really think this basic GUI feature should be integral part of Tk...).

Instructions [here](https://github.com/petasis/tkdnd) seem to refer to adding the extension to a normal installation, not a Framework. I haven't found any explicit instructions. Sorry if the question is naive, but I am very unexperienced of Tcl/Tk. PS: my .app accesses Tk through Perl. I would very much appreciate any help/instructions/link.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use tkdnd, so I do not have a answer specific to that installation.

Adding to my [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53777217/find-precompiled-or-compile-tcl-tk-frameworks-for-macos) I have blocks in my build script such as this one which builds the 'tdom' extension.

```
cd $SRCDIR
cd tdom*
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
  make distclean
  ./configure \
      --exec-prefix=$INSTLOC \
      --prefix=$INSTLOC \
      --with-tcl=$INSTLOC/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/tclConfig.sh
  make CFLAGS="-O2 -mmacosx-version-min=${macosxminver}"
  make install
fi
```

However, linking to the Tk libraries may complicate things.  And every package is different and uses different variables.  So I will need to download tkdnd and build it and see if there are any issues, so expect an upcoming edit to this answer.

***(Edit: I fixed the script in [the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53777217/find-precompiled-or-compile-tcl-tk-frameworks-for-macos), so the following
paragraph no longer applies)***
My changes to the init.tcl script are not quite perfect, as you can see, the wrong package is loaded when I run via 'wish' (wish is in a different location than tclsh, which causes some issues).  I should have the local installation's path located earlier in the `auto_path`.  If you are using my script, you need to be aware of this.

```
bll-mac:$ ../darwin/64/tcl/bin/tclsh
% package require tdom
0.9.1

bll-mac$ ../darwin/64/tcl/bin/wish
% package require tdom
0.8.3
% package require tdom 0.9.1
0.9.1
```

There really isn't any difference between a [framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618027/what-exactly-is-a-framework-in-mac-os-x-framework-folders) (and [b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444543/differences-between-framework-and-non-framework-builds-of-python-on-mac-os-x)) and a normal installation, the framework just provides a structure for resource location.

**Edit**:

It appears that the following works to compile and install the tkdnd package.
The redefinition of PKG_CFLAGS is necessary because the tkdnd makefile
has an argument defined that is not supported by the compiler (on Mojave).
So PKG_CFLAGS is a copy of what's in the makefile without `-fobjc-gc`.

I only tried doing a `package require tkdnd`.  I don't know how to use
the package, so I did not try anything else.

```
cd $SRCDIR
cd tkdnd*
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
  make distclean
  ./configure \
      --prefix=$INSTLOC \
      --exec-prefix=$INSTLOC \
      --with-tcl=$INSTLOC/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework \
      --with-tk=$INSTLOC/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework
  make CLAGS_OPTIMIZE="-O2 -mmacosx-version-min=${macosxminver}" \
       PKG_CFLAGS="-DMAC_TK_COCOA -std=gnu99 -x objective-c"
  make install
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to install the extension in the standard path (/usr/local/lib) but not in the Tk.framework. Probably the "make instal" should require some extra values.